# Speed up AWS PostgreSQL insertion via Python script

Tags: python, database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, multiprocessing

I have 120,000 csv inside my AWS EC2 instance, each containing 120,000 rows. I can't insert each of them as is into my AWS RDS postgresql DB, that will be 120,000^2 = 14,400,000,000 records. Each csv is about 2 MB.

My approach is:

- Python script that converts 120,000 records into just 1 record (list of dictionary) for each csv (now 5 MB after condensing the data) with the help of `pandas` library
- The python script then insert each csv's 1 record into AWS postgresql database via `pandas.to_sql` (which uses `sqlalchemy`
- I use python multiprocessing module to fully utilize my AWS EC2 to speed up data insertion
- I did not create additional indexes in order to speed up my data insertion
- I use AWS EC2 instance with up to 25GB of network connection

My observation is:

- At the beginning, my code will insert 50 csv per min, which is decent speed
- However, right now, with 50k csv being inserted, it only insert 1k csv in 5 hours, about 3.33 csv per min
- I tried using psql `\copy` and realized that it takes between 30-50 sec to insert 1 csv, that's slower than my script that converts the data and insert into the DB directly

I am not sure how I can speed up things up.

Comment: `\copy` would create a record for each CSV row resulting in 14.4 billion records; maybe you can post the structure of the files and the table?

Comment: Do you have any indexes, constraints in the target table? If yes, I suggest dropping them before insert and recreating them after all files have been imported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the database performance drop from 50 to 3.33 csv per min is because of the AWS RDS instance class.

I am using `db.t2.micro` class, which I just learnt that it's limited by CPU credits. After I change the instance class to `t3`, my code is back to 50 csv per min.

> Amazon RDS T3 DB instances run in Unlimited mode, which means that you will be charged if your average CPU utilization over a rolling 24-hour period exceeds the baseline of the instance. CPU Credits are charged at $0.075 per vCPU-Hour. The CPU Credit pricing is the same for all T3 instance sizes across all regions and is not covered by Reserved Instances.

Considering that my code takes <1 sec to execute, and only 1 record to insert each time. `pandas.to_sql` shouldn't be the bottleneck. Though I do believe using SQLAlchemy will perform better than `pandas.to_sql`. For the same reason `psycopg2` performs better than `SQLAlchemy`.

In short, this is an issue due to hardware rather than software. Fix it by upgrading to a more powerful instance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I always find sql operations in pandas to be slow, have your tried taking your dictionary directly and inserting it via sqlalchemy?

Something like this, where dict_list is your dict:

````
sql = """INSERT INTO %s %s VALUES (%ss)"""
columns_string = '('+','.join(dict_list[0].keys())+')'
values_string = '%('+')s,%('.join(dict_list[0].keys())+')'
database_connection.execute(
    sql % (table_name, 
           columns_string, 
           values_string), 
           dict_list)```
````

Comment: I needed `pandas` to condense 120,000 rows into just 1 row. Which is why I use `pandas.to_sql` since it uses sqlalchemy. What is the performance difference between using `pandas.to_sql` vs `sqlalchemy`? I don't have any benchmark for that

Comment: @shawnngtq when I was using to_sql to insert it took 50s of ms, when I went straight to sql it took les than around 5 ms (numbers off the top of my head)

How many csvs do you process concurrently?